# Using exsiting target as base for a new, but related target

Tags: cmake

Say I have a cmake script with:

```
...
add_executable(ABC abc.cpp)
...
```

with some properties set, libraries linked etc.

Now I'd like to define a derived target, say `ABC-extended` based on `ABC` in the same CMakeLists.txt file, that would have all the same properties, libraries linked etc, but with a couple of new compiler flags passed say `-O3` or whatever, without redefining all that.

I.e., I'd like something like this (fictional functions used):

```
add_derived_executable(ABC2 FROM ABC)
add_target_compile_options(ABC2 PUBLIC -O3)
```

Comment: Just create a macro for creating the target in it's base form that allows you to specify the target name, create both targets this way and then apply all the settings specific to each of those targets. Alternatively you could store info in variables in a way that makes it simple&short to reuse the info to create the individual targets. E.g. you could store all the sources in a list variable and simply use `add_executable(ABC ${ABC_SOURCES}) add_executable(ABC2 ${ABC_SOURCES})`.

Comment: @fabian sources are the same. Is there really no simpler way? How about multiple build configurations (like the built in Release or Debug)?

Comment: I assumed you wanted both to exist in the same configuration in parallel, but of course it's possible use different configurations, if you don't. You just need to be sure all the options that are different can be set via generator expressions and/or configuration dependent properties. Which one is preferrable basically depends on how you want both targets to be used.

Comment: @fabian actually you were right the first time and that's what I wanted, I was just guessing that perhaps this behavior can be molded somehow to what I want.

Comment: Do you have control over `add_executable(ABC`?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, I do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [INTERFACE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) library as base target that holds all your common flags/sources/properties (a.k.a. [*usage requirements*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements)). Those can then be propagated to all your derived libraries via `target_link_libraries()`:

```cpp
# base library
add_library(ABC-base)
target_compile_options(ABC-base INTERFACE ...)
target_sources(ABC-base INTERFACE ...)

# derived libraries
add_library(ABC)
target_link_libraries(ABC PRIVATE ABC-base)
add_library(ABC-extended)
target_link_libraries(ABC-extended PRIVATE ABC-base)
target_compile_options(ABC-extended PRIVATE -O3)
```

Note, that the base target should be "linked" `PRIVATE`ly against the derived ones, to prevent the flags/sources/properties of the base target being passed on to other targets that link against e.g. the `ABC` library.

Comment: sounds splendid! How about `add_executable`? It probably cannot be defined at the INTERFACE level, so I need to add after derived's `add_library` correct?

Comment: Alright, it turns out it doesn't work this way. I'm trying to make custom executables not libraries...

Comment: The base target (`ABC-base`) needs to be a library, since there is no such thing as "`INTERFACE` executables". But since the base target is really just a collection of requirements (flags, sources, etc.) and does not produce any binary, it doesn't really matter if it's a library or executable. The derived targets (`ABC` and `ABC-extended`) can of course be executables.